# multiple key pressed doesn't work in Godot

Tags: godot

**Tried two keys in input map but run code even single key is pressed**

```
if event.is_action_pressed("ui_up") && event.is_action_pressed("ui_left"): //doesn't work

if event.is_action_pressed("ui_up"): //worked
```

Comment: The code above is querying the `event` if it is the actions ui_left and ui_up and is pressed. This won’t happen because those two actions are assigned to different keys and would be sent as individual events. When you want to query the global state of input use the Input singleton. In this case use [Input.is_action_pressed](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_input.html#class-input-method-is-action-pressed).

Answer (score 1):

You are going to get a call to `_input` per input event. And the `event` object you get as parameter in `_input` represents that single input.

So, as Hola correctly explained in comments, you are not going to get an `event` object that reports both actions being pressed, because those actions are set to different keys and would be sent as individual events.

If you only care if the input is presser or not, you can query `Input`, for example:

```
if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_up") and Input.is_action_pressed("ui_left"):
    pass
```

And that does not have to be in `_input`. *In fact, I would argue against using `_input` unless you really need to.* You can do that check in `_process` or `_physics_process` instead.

---

Now, something tells me that you don't only want to know if they were pressed, you also will want to know if they were pressed "at the same time" (for some definition of "at the same time").

Again, the easier way to do it is simply checking `Input`:

```
if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_up") and Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_left"):
    pass
```

And I need to tell you that `is_action_just_pressed` is not intended to work - and may cause unintended results - if used in `_input`. For an explanation of that see [Godot - Input.is_action_just_pressed() runs twice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69982843/402022).

And if you need more control over what "at the same time" means, or you are going to do it in `_input` anyway, I'm going to remit you to an older answer on the sister site for game development: [How to make two keys pressed to make an action?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/191513/10408)